# Retrieving sum of records between two dates (C#.net, sql)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two textboxes where a user can enter dates through a calendar picker, a start date and an end date. I want to retrieve the sum of records between these two dates, however when I run my code it seems to give strange sum counts that differ between dates, the sums are completely wrong. One issue is that the dates aren't all in the same format in the database and the second issue is that I want the total sum of records in the entire database if no dates are chosen. How can I modify my SQL statement below to retrieve the proper results?

```
using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM JournalEntries WHERE JournalDate BETWEEN'" + txtStartDate.Text + "' and '" + txtEndDate.Text + "'", con))
```

The dates are in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: You need to make sure that the text boxes are in a format recognized by SQL, but at the same time, you also need to make sure i cant add injections.  Your code as is, i could just drop and create tables etc all in your statement

Comment: When you say _One issue is that the dates aren't all in the same format in the database_ Does that mean you are storing date as varchar/nvarchar instead of datetime?

Comment: If you are using a `DateTimePicker`, to get the displayed date use `.Value` property. There is no such thing as text in a `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: Please post more code.

Answer (score 1):

First you need two commands.

1. For All Records
2. For Date-wise Records

You need to make sure that the date you are sending using text boxes is in proper format. Generally the format is yyyy-MM-dd.

Also, your database columns for Date should be of type date not varchar or anything else. That should help maintain uniformity for all dates stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a `DateTimePicker` here is some code that will tell you the difference between the values of two `DateTimePickers` along with a formatted String representing the difference.

```
// dTP = DateTimePicker
DateTime startTime = dTPStart.Value;
DateTime endTime = dTPEnd.Value;
TimeSpan diff = endTime - startTime;
String difStr = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)difStr.TotalHours, difStr.Minutes, difStr.Seconds);
```

As for your database, that's all I know about it. Its yours. I am not sure what calendar format it uses.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the dates in the database are stored as date, txtdate.text should work. I suppose you are trying to get sum of a some field then,

```
    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Sum(your field) As MYSUM FROM JournalEntries WHERE JournalDate between (your dates) Group by (your field)), conn)
```

and lets say if you did not select any dates, you need to somehow know that the user didn't select the dates, then use if else to determine which query to execute, and of course the second query will be without the where clause...I hope it works for you, I am sorry if I wasn't any help